# Trying to write in already existing *.xlsx file causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, xlsx

following is my function

```
 public static void writeOutputExtraInfo(
        HueIfxModuleMasterStruct<OutputEngineIfxJobMasterStruct> 
    ifxModuleMasterStruct, String filePath)
        throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    //XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(file);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    writeOutputExtraBasicInfo(ifxModuleMasterStruct, workbook);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
    workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
    fileOutputStream.close();
    workbook.close();

}
```

I get the following error

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.getProperties(POIXMLDocument.java:159) ~[poi-ooxml-3.13.jar:3.13]
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:210) ~[poi-ooxml-3.13.jar:3.13]
```

can someone tell whats wrong with the code.

Comment: Which line in your code causes the nullP? workbook.write?

Comment: Can you try this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956535/apache-poi-file-getting-corrupted-and-unable-to-write-to-existing-workbook

Comment: what makes you think that it's because the file already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way?

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
```

So, obtaining the Workbook instance from the FileInputStream.

Comment: [This URL](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) advises to use File and not FileInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comment in the javadoc for the constructor of XSSFWorkbook:

> Once you have finished working with the Workbook, you should close the
>   package by calling POIXMLDocument.close(), to avoid leaving file
>   handles open.

So my guess is that the exception is due to the fact that the file is open, not because it exists.